# how to count occurrences of an entry in google sheet or excel

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet with the following data

```
City    Random
Newyork 12
Newyork 12
Bangkok 4234
Bangkok 1242
Bangkok 23
```

Another sheet should count the occurrences as follows and should be an array formula.

```
City    Number of entries
Newyork 2
Bangkok 3
```

How can i achieve it. I have tried a lookup with countif but returns false.

Comment: Could [this](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/avoid-auto-sorting-when-using-query-group-by-clause/) be helpfull?

Comment: i prefer to use the vlookup formula as i have fixed range in sheet 2

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Sheets Query:

```
=query(A:C,"Select A,count(A) where A is not null group by A label count(A) 'Number of entries'")
```

[image]

Query with group by automatically sorts on the grouping variable. If you need to preserve the order you could use Unique and Countif instead:

```
=ArrayFormula({unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),countif(A2:A,unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")))})
```

Comment: thanks. i have a set fields for column D. hence i cannot display the column D in random order

Comment: OK well I think you would have to use Unique instead - will add it to my answer.